# problems displaying html characters

Tags: php, html, html-entities

I'm building a sign-in/up form and I have problems displaying HTML characters. When a user signs up, I use this function for the sign-up data and then insert it into the database.

```
function clearInput( $string) {
  $string = stripslashes($string);
  return htmlentities($string);
}
```

When a user signs-up with the name `<p>hello</p>` it will look like this in the db: `"&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;hello&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt"<br>`.

If the user signs-in and I `var_dump` the name that is saved in the session it looks like this `<br>'&lt;p&gt;hello&lt;/p&gt;'` in the browser.

If I echo this `&lt;p&gt;hello&lt;/p&gt;` manually in the document, it displays this `<p>hello\</p>` as it should normally.

Does someone know how it shows `<p>hello</p>` when I `var_dump` the session name?

Comment: Don't know why you need it like that in a `var_dump` but https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: That function, put up on the t'internet years ago is the bane of sensible dev's lives. **Throw it away** and use proper [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: Don't use `htmlentities`. Only use that for outputting. You'll run into issues down the road when you try to select a row with an accent and find out it is an entity instead of the char...

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm using prepared statements with PDO to insert the data.

Comment: Now i use html_entity_decode instead of htmlentities this works I get the result that I want. I'm also using prepared statements is this enough security?

Comment: _I'm using prepared statements with PDO to insert the data_ Then I am not sure why you are using this function??

Comment: Get rid of all `clearInput()` usages and use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php in its place.. it should only be used for outputting, not for inserting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your question but it will help you.

```
$str = "This is some &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt; text.";
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
This is some <b>bold</b> text.


$str = '&lt;a href=&quot;https://www.test.com&quot;&gt;test.com&lt;/a&gt;';
echo html_entity_decode($str);
<a href="https://www.test.com">test.com</a>
```